# Java. Наследование

Tags: java, наследование

С наследованием Room класса Flat проблем нет.Всё выводит корректно(извиняюсь за некрасивый вывод, по ходу подправлю ).Но как наследовать Flat для класса Flat_town , к сожалению, мне пока не понятно. Появляются следующие ошибки при компиляции :  error: call to super must be first statement in constructor.Попыталась переставить `super(flour);` и  `super(kitchenar);` выше, но компилятор всё равно не доволен. Подскажите, как осуществить это "наследование наследника" корректно?

(Я только начинаю разбираться с Java , не ругайте сильно :))

```
 class Room{
  double area;
  public Room(double area){
  this.area=area;
  }
}

 class Flat extends Room{
  int flour;
  double kitchenar;
  public Flat(double area,int floor,double kitchenar){
  super(area);
  this.floor=floor;
  this.kitchenar=kitchenar;
  }
}
 class Flat_town extends Flat{
  String town;
  public Flat_town(double area,int floor,double kitchenar, String town){
  super(area);
  super(floor);
  super(kitchenar);
  this.town=town;
  }
}
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    Flat flat1 = new Flat(12,3,15);
    System.out.println("Площадь комнаты "+ flat1.area + " Этаж " + flat1.floor +" Площадь кухни "+ flat1.kitchenar);
    Flat_town flat_town1 = new Flat_town(13,4,17,"Москва");
    System.out.println("Площадь комнаты "+ flat_town1.area + " Этаж " + flat_town1.floor +" Площадь кухни "+ flat_town1.kitchenar+"Город"+ flat_town1.town);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super(...)` в конструкторе - это вызов конструктора родительского класса, у которого три параметра.

```
super(area, floor, kitchenar);
```

Comment: ну вот, умеете же писать ответы длиннее куска кода!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin "Доктор, это Вам!"